How to use Polylang with posts index homepage
I have my WP homepage set to show "latest posts" in the Reading settings, not a static page. I would like to keep this (for the theme's templates reasons). How do I get the /en version of homepage to work with Polylang? Currently it redirects me to my default language's home (/cz)
In the Docs I found only an answer how to do the opposite (define home as static).
[EDIT: I'm using a child theme which created my problem. The default Polylang bahavior does nicely what I was asking for. Apologies.]

you want that /cz show lasts post in Czech (not sur for the language name) and /en lasts posts in English ?

Yes. I want mydomain.com/cz to be the default homepage using the "Latest posts" option in Reading - listing latest posts in Czech - and mydomain.com/en the homepage styled the same but with English menu and listing English posts.

your problem is strange because what you want is working on my test website. do you have this configuration ? https://i.sstatic.net/rULaYvMk.png

@mmm yes I do. Take a look. This works https://www.anthropocene.cz/en/new-publication-out/ but this doesn't https://www.anthropocene.cz/en/ . I guess the problem is connected with no page id assigned to index page (nor its translation) as it just renders through index template. Do you have a posts page / home page created on your test site?

I don't have a posts page and in the reading settings I have set "Your homepage displays : Your latest posts".

@mmm thanks for leading me right, the problem was my child theme hacking into pre_get_posts (where it set the posts category to a Czech one). Switching theme uncovered this, if you make it an answer I will mark it as the right one.

Just change the star next to the default language under /wp-admin/admin.php?page=mlang to the desired language.
Example:

The redirect might be due to the redirect setting by the browser language detection. That is, if your browser's language is CZ, it will redirect to that. You can change that (detection of the browser preferred language) with disabling it under:
/wp-admin/admin.php?page=mlang_settings
Further reference:
https://polylang.pro/doc/detect-the-browser-preferred-language/

I was not asking how to set the default language to en, my default language is cz. However even if I change it to en, the homepage remains redirecting to /cz, which is weird.

I only want mydomain.com/en to stop redirecting to mydomain.com/cz. I cannot do it by adding a translation to a page as there is no such page. It is the "Latest posts" template set up in Reading, not a "Static page".

I've updated my answer.

Thx for the idea, but I have browser language detection disabled.
